# SELECT DISTINCT on a field not appearing in recordset?

Tags: sql, database-agnostic

I want to do a `SELECT DISTINCT guid, ...`, but I don't want `guid` appearing in the recordset. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a subselect?

```
select my, interesting, columns
from (
    select distinct GUID, ...
    from ...
)
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as it would have returned everything, this is the correct solution +1!

Comment: I have to choose this one as the answer, because it actually has an English answer in it! :P

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT a.Field2
     , a.Field3
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.guid
                      , a.Field2
                      , a.Field3
                   FROM table1 a)  a
```

Comment: damn, you were 20 seconds faster ;-)

Comment: That's why he has the gold :)

Comment: @meriton - :)  At least we both arrived at the same solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
SELECT x, y FROM tbl GROUP BY guid, x, y
```

The drawback here is that you have to duplicate the column list in the `GROUP BY` clause, which is annoying, but the other answers do as well.

Answer (score 0):

select the distinct values into a temp table first.

Then select out only the values you want.